# Filtering Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3, footable

when I filter the Gridview I lose the Footable function. 
Strange behavior, if I click on the filter button, filter by brand and select the Pireli option, then click the update button.

I lose the Footable function, but if I then click the Update button again leaving the filter as Pireli the Footable function returns!!!!!

Seeing is believing if you navigate to the following url www.tyrescanner.net

Enter registration WR08SZE
Enter postcode KA227PR

Sorry for the jumping around here.

If you click on the filer Brand option and select Pireli, the Gridview will lose the Footable function, but if you click again on the Update button the Footable function returns!!!!!!!!

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" runat="server">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/css/footable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/js/footable.min.js"></script>




<%--Resizing Gridview--%>
<script>
    $(function () {
        AttachjQueryFootableToTable();
    });

    function AttachjQueryFootableToTable() {
        $('[id*=GridView1]').footable();
    }
</script>

<script>
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        AttachjQueryFootableToTable();
    });
</script>
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-0 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblRegText" runat="server" Text="Tyre Size:  " Style="font-weight: 700; font-size: x-large" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbltyresize" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 700; font-size: x-large" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
        <a href="http://tyrescanner.net/pages/edit-tyre-size.aspx">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEdit" runat="server" Text=" Edit" Style="font-size: large" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter">Filter</span></button>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="width: 130px">
                        <h5><strong>Brand</strong></h5>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SRDDLBrand" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceBrand" DataTextField="TyreBrands" DataValueField="TyreBrands" Height="35px" Width="105px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value=" " />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="width: 130px">
                        <h5><strong>Season</strong></h5>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SRDDLTyreType" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTyreType" DataTextField="TyreType" DataValueField="TyreType" Height="35px" Width="105px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value=" " />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="width: 130px">
                        <h5><strong>Fuel Efficiency</strong></h5>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SRDDLFuelCat" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceFuelCategory" DataTextField="TyreCategory" DataValueField="TyreCategory" Height="35px" Width="105px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value=" " />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="width: 130px">
                        <h5><strong>Wet Grip</strong></h5>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SRDDLWetGrip" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceWetGrip" DataTextField="TyreCategory" DataValueField="TyreCategory" Height="35px" Width="105px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value=" " />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <p></p>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                        <asp:Button ID="bntFilter" runat="server" OnClick="bntFIlter_Click" Text="Update Results" CssClass="btn Jumbt btn-custom" Style="color: white" role="button" Height="44px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br />


<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="footable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="max-width: 130%" AutoPostback="Flash" DataKeyNames="ProductID,GarageID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGridViewSearchResults"
            EmptyDataText="Sorry we don’t have that tyre, please email us your requirements and we will add it to our Search engine – service@tyrescanner.net"
            OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
            <Columns>
                <%--  0--%>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" Visible="false" />
                <%--1--%>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GarageID" HeaderText="GarageID" Visible="false" />
                <%-- 2--%>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GarageTown" HeaderText="Garage Location"></asp:BoundField>

                <%-- 3--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tyre Model">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBrand" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Brand")+ " " + Eval("TyreModel")%>'></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="£" Height="16px" Width="4px" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCurrency" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%#Eval("ProductUnitSalePrice")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <%--  4--%>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TyreType" HeaderText="Tyre Type" />
                <%--  5  --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Noise Level">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNoiseEmission" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NoiseEmission")+ "dB"%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="FuelEfficiencyCategory" HeaderText="Fuel Efficiency" />
                <%--  6   --%>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WetGrip" HeaderText="Wet Grip" />
                <%--  7   --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Quantity">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="txtQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true" Width="55px" Height="32px" DataFormatString="{0:£ 0.0}" ForeColor="Black">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value=" " />
                            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Label ID="Errorlabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><p></p>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelTotalPoundSign" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Total £" Height="16px" Width="4px"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                              <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="0.00" Width="30px"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="btnOrder_Click" CommandName="Select" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm" Style="color: white">Order &raquo;</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Do you have any code for us to see or should we shake our crystal ball ?

Comment: Share your code.